# Serve up s3 file with nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I have some static files sitting in an S3 bucket that I want to serve up from my `nginx` server. Basically, if a user goes to `www.mywebsite.com/this/url` I want to serve them up a file from the S3 bucket. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Did you consider perhaps just using a CNAME record? That way you could just use something like `content.example.com` (the bucket has to be named the same). (ErikA beat me by a few seconds on this one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why bring nginx into the mix? Just serve the file up to the user's browser directly out of S3.

To do this, ensure that the ACL on your S3 bucket allows read access from anonymous users. The URLs to your files there are as follows:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/<file_name>
```

You can also create a CNAME record to serve S3 files from your own domain. Keep in mind that the bucket name has to be identical to the domain you'll be using (i.e. `static.example.com`) - see [S3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingExistingDomainOnS3.html) for more info on that.

Comment: I kind of wanted to make it look like it was coming from my server, but I guess serving it up directly from S3 won't be so bad. And it will reduce load on my server.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum - Appearances are over-rated. 99.99999% of users don't know nor care where webpage assets come from. You know what *isn't* over-rated? Speed and reliability, both of which will increase by pulling the files directly from S3. :)

Comment: You know what, you're right. Well said. I guess my only question then would be access control (beyond the simple "this is public" and "this is private"). But that's a new question to ask :)

Comment: @ErikA The speed gain isn't really that noticeable and if the DNS server goes down, the main site would be affected either way. However, with a CNAME record, you're putting those few less bytes of strain on the server from the shorter url on embedded or linked content (Well, they do add up! :) ), and there isn't any need to change the actual website if you decide to move from S3 to a different service. The miniscule speed loss is worth it, IMO.

Comment: @ErikA - I disagree that using S3 will improve normal performance.  Average reposne time for s3 can approach 800ms (you can serve yourself *much* faster than this). It was not intended as a CDN, rather a storage mechanism (Cloudfront is the CDN offering).  Reliability will be better of course, as will relative performance at high scales.